# How to setup this triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $D$ be the region in $\mathbf R^3$ that lies above the surface $z=x^2+y^2-1$and below the surface$z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. Sketch the region of $D$ together with its projection on the $XY$-plane and evaluate the integral $\iiint z dV$.

$z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ is a semi-sphere with radius $1$ and  $z=x^2+y^2-1$ is a paraboloid to find the intersection I set them equal.

$\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}=x^2+y^2-1$

${-(-1+x^2+y^2)}=(x^2+y^2-1)^2$

$-1=x^2+y^2-1$

$x^2+y^2=0$ this is not what I expected i ecpected a circle with raduis 1 to be projected on the $XY$-plane

What am I doing or interpreting wrong?

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates may be helpful.

Comment: $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\ge 0\to 1-x^2-y^2\ge 0\to x^2+y^2-1\le0\to x^2+y^2-1=0$

Comment: The "wrong" is then dividing by $x^2+y^2-1=0$, i.e. division by zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}=x^2+y^2-1$
>
> ${-(-1+x^2+y^2)}=(x^2+y^2-1)^2$
>
> $-1=x^2+y^2-1$

Your last line is wrong. Let $A=x^2+y^2-1$. Your second line gives
$$
-A=A^2
$$
which implies $A(A+1)=0$ and thus $A=-1$ **or** $A=0$. You just picked the wrong one since $A\geq 0$ by your first line.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the intersection of:

$$z = \rho^2-1$$
$$z^2 = 1 - \rho^2$$

where $\rho^2 = x^2 + y^2$.  Add the two equations to get $z^2 + z = 0$, so $z = -1,0$.  For the $z=0$ solution, $\rho^2 = 1$ which is what you suspected.